# Getting 'method not exist' error for PeristedModel.findOrCreate()

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to use the method Model.findOrCreate in loopback using the mongodb connector

```
Country.findOrCreate({where: {iso2a: iso2a}}, {
                        "iso2a": iso2a,
                        "polygon": polygon
                    }, function(err, obj){
                        if(err){
                            console.log("Error finding and/or creating:", err);
                        }else{
                            obj.iso2a = iso2a;
                            obj.polygon = polygon;

                            obj.save(function(err, obj){
                                if(err){
                                    console.log("Error saving");
                                }else{
                                    console.log("Success saving");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

But I keep getting the error that the function does not exists...

I guess I am doing something pretty basic wrong, ohh yeah and I checked that the model is "loaded". 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read the docs [here](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-findorcreate) for PersistedModel.findOrCreate(where, data, callback). Now you see the first argument only accepts `where` clause, so you don't have to specify it explicitly. Here's the corrected code:

```
Country.findOrCreate(
    { iso2a: iso2a },    //adding where clause is not required.
    {
        "iso2a": iso2a,
        "polygon": polygon
    },
    function(err, obj) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error finding and/or creating:", err);
        } else {
            obj.iso2a = iso2a;
            obj.polygon = polygon;

            obj.save(function(err, obj) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("Error saving");
                } else {
                    console.log("Success saving");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Hope it solves your problem.